# Frequent invalidate of multiple views is very slow / unpredictable

Tags: android, performance, gridview, view

I have a GridView with multiple tiles in it (9-15 visible). Tiles are implemented as custom views.

There are very frequent updates of data ongoing (can be even 1-2 times per second for every visible tile). Let's say every tile has a price which I need to redraw according to the update.

My current approach is to manually call `invalidate(x1,y1,x2,y2)` to request a redraw of a region with a price on update. However it seems very slow and sometimes not all the tiles are updated appropriately. Ideally I would also run a small color change animation to make the update more visible.

Is there a better technique, maybe more low-level to achieve the goal with highest possible performance?